# elasticity - scrollView layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have problem when i design layout in android. This is: in layout, I have 2 components. it's header and content. But I don't know when I scrollView content. header will elasticity.

this like is detail restaurant in foodSpotting app. Who can suggestion or show me ? really I need it ! !

Thanks so much ! !

Comment: i dont understand what you want about the elasticity part.. your explaination is very confusing..

Comment: Do You need smth like pull-to-refresh, like here http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/03/28/the-pull-to-refresh-an-anti-ui-pattern-on-android/ ?

Comment: I'm sorry Francis Fuerte: I mean. in my layout, i have 2 components. linearlayout(id: header) in top with height: 150dp and another linearlayout(id: content - has scrolView). When I moving content to top, layout header will small and overlaps layout header.

Comment: Hi sandrstar. Yeah, exactly ! but how I can do, when I not touch on linearlayout, it's will stay at this position ?

Comment: can you show your layout file

Comment: Hi Peshal, I haven't layout. I'm just design mockup. this is my mockup I design: http://www.flickr.com/photos/92066166@N04/9354046361/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-listview-pull-to-refresh.html

You can try this , Maybe thats working for you .. :)